# What is the best way to sort below result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

For example:

```
Name         Date
A            2018-06-02
B            2018-06-03
B            2018-06-01
C            2018-06-01
```

What is the best way to get:

```
B            2018-06-03
B            2018-06-01
A            2018-06-02
C            2018-06-01
```

Sort order is first by `Order by Date DESC`, but then should follow by all the records for that `Name`

Comment: What's the sort order?

Comment: @dfundako, for your answer, `A` will be the 2nd row, then `B 2018-06-01`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try forcing the max date by each name.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Data') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Data

CREATE TABLE #Data (
    Name VARCHAR(10),
    Date DATE)

INSERT INTO #Data (
    Name,
    Date)
VALUES
    ('A', '2018-06-02'),
    ('B', '2018-06-03'),
    ('B', '2018-06-01'),
    ('C', '2018-06-01')

SELECT
    D.Name,
    D.Date
FROM
    #Data AS D
ORDER BY
    MAX(D.Date) OVER (PARTITION BY D.Name ORDER BY D.Date DESC) DESC,
    D.Date DESC,
    D.Name
```

Comment: Not sure you need th ORDER BY D.Date DESC portion.  Either way +1

Comment: @JohnCappelletti, that is needed :)

Comment: @LONG I was talking about in the window function.  I

Answer (score 3):

Use *window* function :

```
order by count(*) over (partition by name) desc, [date] desc, name
```

For based on date use `max()` function instead

```
order by max([date]) over (partition by name) desc, [date] desc, name
```

Comment: This will order by the amount of rows that share the same name, not by the max date of each different name.

Comment: Thank you, @Yogesh, 2nd one is the one I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

This should get you what you want:

```
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT [name],
           CONVERT(date,[date]) AS [date] --that isn't confusing
    FROM (VALUES ('A','20180602'),('B','20180603'),('B','20180601'),('C','20180601')) V([Name],[date])),
MaxDate AS (
    SELECT *,
           MAX([date]) OVER (PARTITION BY [name]) AS MaxDate
    FROM VTE)
SELECT [name],[date]
FROM MaxDate
ORDER BY MaxDate DESC,
         [date] DESC,
         [name] ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT

---

I recommend you use ExLo's answer.  What I posted was headed in the right direction with window functionality but his seems to match exactly what you need.

---

You should post expected results and possibly more test data to get a better answer.

Without testing I believe this will set you down a good path.

You can use Dense_Rank () Over (Order By Date Desc) As DateRank and Row_Number() Over (Partition By Name Order By Date Desc) As NameDateOrder

If the above is a subquery or cte you can select from that and order by DateRank, NameDateOrder

Comment: Thank you @ Joe, I was looking for a way to avoid using subquery. xD

Answer (score 0):

Use row_number:

```
declare @t as table ([Name] char(1), [Date] date)

insert into @t values
  ('A', '2018-06-02')
, ('B', '2018-06-03')
, ('B', '2018-06-01')
, ('C', '2018-06-01')


    Select t.*, row_number() over (order by md desc) as r
    from
    (
        select [Name], max([date]) md
        from @t
        group by [Name]
        ) x
    inner join @t t on t.[Name] = x.[Name]
```

Comment: hi @cloudsafe, I think one more outer query is needed for order by `r`